# Force Two-Way-Binding to Take Effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing an AngularJS 1.x directive (let's call it `MyDirective`). Its scope is declared as follows:

```
scope: {
    accessor: '='
}
```

In its `link` function, I am assigning a new object to that `accessor` field, like so:

```
scope.accessor = {
    // methods such as doSomethingToMyDirective()
};
```

Now, I am instantiating this directive dynamically with [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

```
var element = $compile('<div data-my-directive data-accessor="directiveAccessor"></div>')(myScope);
```

Once this has run, my current scope (`myScope`) has a `directiveAccessor` property that references the object instance created within the directive.

**Problem: This field is not *immediately* available.**

In other words, once I have run `$compile`, I cannot access `myScope.directiveAccessor` immediately in the next command. When I check the scope later, the field is there, and probably, a single [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) would be sufficient.

With some breakpoints, I can observe that the object is indeed created right when `$compile` is executed; `accessor` on the inner scope already points to the object. However, it seems that the two-way-binding that would copy the value from `accessor` on the inner scope to `myScope.directiveAccessor` does not become active until a later point.

**Is there any way to force AngularJS to copy two-way-bound values immediately (i.e. without waiting for any promise)?**

Comment: You should be accessing the bound variables in lifecycle methods $onInit and $onChanges, for example. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component -- Note these work with any controller, not just component controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use expression binding (`&`) to immediately set a parent scope variable:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        scope: { onPostLink: "&" },
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.accessor = {
            doSomethingToMyDirective: function() {
                return "Hello world";
            }
        };
        scope.onPostLink({$event: scope.accessor});
        scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
            scope.onPostLink({$event: null});
        });
    }
})
```

Usage:

```
<my-directive on-post-link="directiveAccessor=$event">
</my-directive>
```

Be sure to `null` the reference when the isolate scope is destroyed. Otherwise the code risks creating memory leaks.

Comment: Aah, rather than waiting for AngularJS to copy the value from inner to outer scope, I send in a callback that gets supplied with the value immediately and can save it to the outer scope right away. Will try today!